# How to reload in config with angular-ui-router?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm listening to `$stateChangeStart` in my `run` section to redirect to a login page, if the user is not logged in (using my custom `loginProvider` to check).

If the user is not logged in, navigating to `/#/home` successfully changes the url to `/#/login`... This doesn't reload the page though, therefore giving the user access to the home page anyway lol.

So, how do you reload a route?

```
angular.module("app", [
    "app",
    "ui.router"
])
    .config(["$stateProvider", "$urlRouterProvider", "$httpProvider", function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $httpProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state("login", {
                url: "/login",
                templateUrl: "app/login/login.html",
                controller: "loginController",
                authenticate: false
            })
            .state("home", {
                url: "/home",
                templateUrl: "app/home/home.html",
                controller: "homeController",
                authenticate: true
            });

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("login");
    }])
    .run(["$rootScope", "$state", "loginProvider", function ($rootScope, $state, loginProvider) {
        $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
            if (toState.authenticate && !loginProvider.isLoggedIn()) {
                $state.transitionTo("login");
                $state.reload(); // not working
                $state.go("login", {}, {reload: true}); // not working
            }
        });
    }]);
```

I'm using angular version 1.5.1, and angular-ui-router version 0.2.18.

Comment: is show any error?

Comment: @Sandeep No errors, just navigating to `/#/home` changes the url to `/#/login`... but shows the home page anyway. I want it to navigate to *and* reload the login page.

Comment: see my answer may be it's helpful for u

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use **event.preventDefault();**

```
.run(["$rootScope", "$state", "loginProvider", function ($rootScope, $state, loginProvider) {
        $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
            if (toState.authenticate && !loginProvider.isLoggedIn()) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $state.go("login", {}, {reload: true});
            }
        });
    }]);
```

Comment: Thanks @Sandeep! Using `event.preventDefault()` now re-routes to `/#/login` *and* reloads, when not logged in. However now *once logged in*, an `F5` refresh on `/#/home` re-routes back to login...

Comment: I think your condition not correct. check your condition.

Comment: I have added an additional condition as you are suggesting ([see my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36121737/1298685)). This solves the issue, except for an `F5` refresh which will delete the `isLoggedIn` information. *So*, it seems that I need to use `$cookies` to persist data on page refresh. That is a different question, so I will mark this as the answer. Thanks again @Sandeep!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Sandeep's answer, I resolved the majority of routing issues in `$rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart"...` with this code:

```
var isLoggedIn = loginProvider.isLoggedIn();

if (toState.authenticate && !isLoggedIn) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $state.transitionTo("login");

} else if (fromState.name === "home" && isLoggedIn) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $state.transitionTo("home");
}
```

Note that my `isLoggedIn` logic does *not* survive an <kbd>F5</kbd> page refresh -- to do that [angular-cookies](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-cookies), [angular-local-storage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-local-storage), or the like needs to be used to persist data.